# using REST to invoke Google Custom Search API

Tags: java, json, google-api

I need to use a Google Custom Search to get the count of a word from Google. I have created a Google Custom Search Engine and I followed the steps described in this guide:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest

How can I get the count from the response data? Secondly, how can I convert this response into a JSONObject using java?

Also is the Google API free?

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest)

> Important: The JSON/Atom Custom Search API requires the use of an API key, which you can get from the Google APIs console. **The API provides 100 search queries per day for free**. If you need more, you may sign up for billing in the console.

If the custom search engines can serve in JSON format you can set a request header of *Accept: application/json*